# Using Export to excel in list which has exceeded threshold limit

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, export, list-view-threshold

I have a requirement to export all items to excel in a list which has exceeded the threshold limit. I've already tried using power query but since I have some null values in people picker fields in my list, it throws an error. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this as well. I believe I ended up having to use the OData Connection in Excel pointed to ListData.svc to get around it.

Comment: Thanks but i don't think this'll work. I've tried accessing listdata.svc from the browser as well and it throws the same error. Based on my research, i found it was because some values in the people picker field were null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSOM (client object). You can use the ListItemCollectionPosition class to implement paging list item retrieval according to the position of items relative to their collection. Use the RowLimit element to specify the number of items to return per page. You can create a Excel with the Items using OpenXML.

Some links:

https://avnibhatt.wordpress.com/2014/06/10/client-object-model-access-large-listsovercome-listview-threshold-while-accessing-large-list/

http://www.sharepointappie.nl/retrieving-all-items-from-a-list-with-csom/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitemcollectionposition.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to MS Access and you can link to the SharePoint lists then you may be able to use the JetDB lazy-read process to get all the data.
I have worked with lists up to 40k+ records and have been able to run queries.